# send id from iOS app to php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ios, uitableview

Im making an app for storing stores in iphone and I have a simple problem.
I want to delete an store in mysql database by sending id nr to php file when i call the
delete function in xcode
and im trying to with the following code, but it still sends null to my php file.
I want to send (filename.php?id=1) but i get filename.php?id=(null)

What can be the problem?

the number in the butikID is the number i want to send to my php

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //Remove from our NSMutablearray
        NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURLdelete];

        [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kID, butikID]];


        //[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kName, butiksnamn]];

        [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

        NSLog(butikID);

        [butiksArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Delete it from the tableview
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: That means `butilID` is `nil`. Where do you set that variable?

Answer (score 0):

If butikID is a `NSNumber`:

```
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%i", kID, [butikID intValue]]];
```

if is an `int`:

```
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%i", kID, butikID]];
```

Comment: If `butikID` is an `NSNumber`, what's wrong with using `%@` as shown in the original code? And how does this answer the problem that the result is `(null)`?

Comment: Yes if is an NSNumber should be work in anything. Probably is nil

Comment: Thanks for the answer now I have to tell ButikID that it is the same as the row I am removing from the tableview, but how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry? Can you explain better?